# SQL Server 2005: Rename DB Server Instance Name?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-administration

Can somebody tell me how to rename the DB server instance name and a DB name
in SQL Server 2005?

Right Now I Have

```
SERVER/OLDNAME

-- oldnameDB
```

I want to change the server instance and also change the db name.

I have tried:

EXEC sp_renamedb 'oldName', 'newName'

and that has changed the dbname as it appers in the tree directory. 
But, when I do "select @@servername" it is the old name. Also, 
the MDF and LDF files are still the old name.

How do change instance and db names as a clean sweep across the server?

Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, there is no article in MSDN to rename instances. This may be the closest: [How to: Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx).

Frankly I'd reinstall if you want to chance instance name

[sp_renamedb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186217.aspx) (deprecated, use [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269.aspx)) will only change the name in sys.databases. You'll have [detach, rename files, reattach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794(SQL.90).aspx). Or backup/restore WITH MOVE

Answer (score 0):

it's possible with `sp_addserver` and some registry edits

see oj's comment here:

http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/topic15810.aspx

or the other option is re-install and reload the db...